Is there a $\forall$-statement in the language of magmas which is not equivalent to any semi-quasi-equation?
Let our signature be that of a single binary operation $*$, in other words, the signature of magmas. In my previous post, here: Has this generalization of quasi-equations been studied in the mathematical literature?, I defined the notion of a semi-quasi-equation. To recap, a semi-quasi-equation is a conditional, the antecedent of which is a conjunction of finitely many (possibly even $0$) equations, and the consequent of which is a disjunction of finitely many (possibly even $0$) equations. Now, obviously, every semi-quasi-equation is a $\forall$-statement. I am wondering whether there is a sort of converse. That is, does there exist a $\forall$-statement in the language of magmas which is not equivalent to any single semi-quasi-equation? Or even any finite set of semi-quasi-equations, conjoined together?

(i) does there exist a $\forall$-statement in the language of magmas which is not equivalent to any single semi-quasi-equation? (ii) Or even any finite set of semi-quasi-equations, conjoined together?
Question (ii) is already answered here. Namely, Alex Kruckman pointed out that a sentence is a universal sentence if and only if it is logically equivalent to a finite conjunction of of semi-quasi-identities.
The answer to Question (i) is Yes. In the language of one binary operation, the statement that the operation is commutative and associative is universal, but is not equivalent to any single semi-quasi-identity.
Details:

Let $\alpha$ be the Commutative Law $(\forall x)(\forall y)(xy=yx)$ and
let $\beta$
be the Associative Law $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(x(yz)=(xy)z)$. The universal sentence I am considering is $\alpha\wedge \beta$.
I will first argue that if this sentence is equivalent to a single
semi-quasi-identity, then it is equivalent to a single identity.
Suppose that $\alpha\wedge \beta$ is logically equivalent to a semi-quasi-identity, $\Gamma = (\forall \bar{x})(\gamma_1\vee \cdots \vee \gamma_n)$, where each $\gamma_i$ is $\pm \textsf{atomic}$. Choose such a $\Gamma$
equivalent to $\alpha\wedge \beta$
which minimizes $n$. Necessarily $n\geq 1$, and I will argue that $n=1$.
If, instead, the minimum $n$ is greater then $1$, then write $\delta=(\gamma_2\vee \cdots \vee \gamma_n)$.
Then $\alpha\wedge\beta\equiv \Gamma=(\forall \bar{x})(\gamma_1\vee \delta)$,
but the minimality of $n$ implies that both $(\forall \bar{x})\gamma_1$ and
$(\forall \bar{x})\delta$ are strictly stronger than $\alpha\wedge\beta$.
There must exist models $A$ and $B$ of $\alpha\wedge\beta$
such that $A\not\models (\forall \bar{x})\gamma_1$
and $B\not\models (\forall \bar{x})\delta$.
Assume that $\bar{a}$ in $A$ fails $\gamma_1$ and
$\bar{b}$ in $B$ fails $\delta$. Then $(\bar{a},\bar{b})$
in $A\times B$ fails $\gamma_1$ and fails $\delta$, so
$A\times B\not\models \Gamma$.
On the other hand, since $A$ and $B$ both satisfy
$\alpha\wedge\beta$, $A\times B$ must satisfy $\alpha\wedge\beta$,
since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are identities.
This contradicts $\alpha\wedge\beta\equiv \Gamma$.
The previous paragraph explains why, if $\alpha\wedge\beta$
is equivalent to a single
semi-quasi-identity, then it is equivalent to one of the form
$\Gamma=(\forall \bar{x})\gamma_1$ with a single disjunct
in the body. We know that the single disjunct
must be $\pm \textsf{atomic}$, but in fact it cannot
be negated atomic if $\alpha\wedge\beta\equiv \Gamma$.
The reason for this is that $\alpha\wedge \beta$ has
a $1$-element model, since it is a conjunction of identities,
but $(\forall \bar{x})\gamma_1$ will not have a $1$-element
model if $\gamma_1$ is negated atomic.
So far, we have learned that if a conjunction of identities
is equivalent to a single semi-quasi-identity, then
it is equivalent to a single identity. On the other hand,
we know
that the conjunction of the
commutative law and the associative law is not
equivalent to a single identity.
It follows that the conjunction of the
commutative law and the associative law is not
equivalent to a single semi-quasi-identity.
